# DataAnnotations and ModelState.IsValid no working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have annotations in two models, the two are related, ModelState.IsValid returns false when there are annotations, delete annotations if it works without problem, anyone know why this happens?

Model 1:

```
    namespace SifActivoFijo.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class AF_UbicacionActivoFijo
    {
        public long IdUbicacion { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "1*")]
        [Display(Name = "Codigo Centro de Costo")]
        public string GN_CentroDeCosto_CodigoCentroDeCosto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "2*")]
        [Display(Name = "Tercero")]
        public string GN_Persona_CodigoPersona { get; set; }
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "3*")]
        [Display(Name = "Codigo Activo")]
        public string AF_ActivoFijo_CodigoActivoFijo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "4*")]
        [Display(Name = "Contacto")]
        public string Contacto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "5*")]
        [Display(Name = "Direccion")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "6*")]
        [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "7*")]
        [Display(Name = "Celular")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9 ]*\.?[0-9 ]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "8*")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "9*")]
        [Display(Name = "Responsable")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Responsable { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "10*")]
        [Display(Name = "Documento")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Responsable_documento { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "11*")]
        [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Responsable_Telefono { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "12*")]
        [Display(Name = "Sucursal")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Sucursal { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "13*")]
        [Display(Name = "N° Contrato")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .@#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string NoContrato { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "14*")]
        [Display(Name = "Ciudad")]
        public string GN_Nivel3_CodigoNivel3 { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "15*")]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha Inicial")]
        public System.DateTime FechaInicial { get; set; }

        public virtual GN_Nivel3 GN_Nivel3 { get; set; }
        public virtual AF_ActivoFijo AF_ActivoFijo { get; set; }
        public virtual GN_Persona GN_Persona { get; set; }
        public virtual GN_CentroDeCosto GN_CentroDeCosto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model 2:

```
    namespace SifActivoFijo.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class AF_ActivoFijo
    {
        public AF_ActivoFijo()
        {
            this.AF_ConfiguracionActivoFijo = new HashSet<AF_ConfiguracionActivoFijo>();
            this.AF_DepreciacionActivoFijo = new HashSet<AF_DepreciacionActivoFijo>();
            this.AF_UbicacionActivoFijo = new HashSet<AF_UbicacionActivoFijo>();
            this.AF_RevaluacionNIIF = new HashSet<AF_RevaluacionNIIF>();
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*1")]
        [Display(Name = "Activo Fijo Principal")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9 .#_-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9 .#_-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string CodigoActivoFijo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*2")]
        [Display(Name = "Grupo Contable")]
        public string AF_GrupoContableAF_CodigoGrupoContableAF { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*3")]
        [Display(Name = "Estado")]
        public string ST_Estado_CodigoEstado { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*4")]
        [Display(Name = "Grupo de Activo")]
        public string AF_GrupoActivoFijo_CodigoGrupoAF { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*5")]
        [Display(Name = "Producto")]
        public string GN_Portafolio_CodigoPortafolio { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Serial")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9 .ñÑ#_-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9 .Ññ#_-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Configurable")]
        public bool SenConfigurable { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*6")]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Activacion")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaActivacion { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*7")]
        [Display(Name = "Costo")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9 ]*\.?[0-9 ]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public Nullable<double> Costo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*8")]
        [Display(Name = "IVA")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9 ]*\.?[0-9 ]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public Nullable<double> ValorIva { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*9")]
        [Display(Name = "Margen")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9 ]*\.?[0-9 ]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public Nullable<double> PorcentajeMargen { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Costo Activo")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9 ]*\.?[0-9 ]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public Nullable<double> CostoActivo { get; set; }
         [Display(Name = "Tiempo Contable")]
        public Nullable<int> TiempoDepreciacionContable { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tiempo Fiscal")]
        public Nullable<int> TiempoDepreciacionFiscal { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Depreciable Individiual")]
        public bool SenDepreciacionIndividual { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Saldo Contable")]
        public Nullable<double> SaldoADepreciar { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*10")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z_0-9\s .#&ñ'-]*\.?[A-Za-z_0-9\s .#&Ñ'-]+", ErrorMessage = "**")]
        public string DescripcionActivoFijo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Saldo Fiscal")]
        public Nullable<double> SaldoAdepreciarFiscal { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Depreciable")]
        public bool SenDepreciable { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*11")]
        [Display(Name = "Propietario")]
        public string GN_Persona_CodigoPersona { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> SaldoNiif { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VidaUtilNiif { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaReevaluacion { get; set; }

        public virtual AF_GrupoActivoFijo AF_GrupoActivoFijo { get; set; }
        public virtual AF_GrupoContableAF AF_GrupoContableAF { get; set; }
        public virtual GN_Portafolio GN_Portafolio { get; set; }
        public virtual ST_Estado ST_Estado { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AF_ConfiguracionActivoFijo> AF_ConfiguracionActivoFijo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AF_DepreciacionActivoFijo> AF_DepreciacionActivoFijo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AF_UbicacionActivoFijo> AF_UbicacionActivoFijo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AF_RevaluacionNIIF> AF_RevaluacionNIIF { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(AF_UbicacionActivoFijo ubicacion)
    {
        AF_UbicacionActivoFijo au = new AF_UbicacionActivoFijo { 

            IdUbicacion=ubicacion.IdUbicacion,
            GN_CentroDeCosto_CodigoCentroDeCosto=ubicacion.GN_CentroDeCosto_CodigoCentroDeCosto,
            GN_Persona_CodigoPersona=ubicacion.GN_Persona_CodigoPersona,
            AF_ActivoFijo_CodigoActivoFijo=ubicacion.AF_ActivoFijo_CodigoActivoFijo,
            Contacto=ubicacion.Contacto,
            Direccion=ubicacion.Direccion,
            Telefono=ubicacion.Telefono,
            Celular=ubicacion.Celular,
            Email=ubicacion.Email,
            Responsable=ubicacion.Responsable,
            Responsable_documento=ubicacion.Responsable_documento,
            Responsable_Telefono=ubicacion.Responsable_Telefono,
            Sucursal=ubicacion.Sucursal,
            NoContrato=ubicacion.NoContrato,
            GN_Nivel3_CodigoNivel3=ubicacion.GN_Nivel3_CodigoNivel3,
            FechaInicial=ubicacion.FechaInicial
        };
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(au).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("confirm", "Home");
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (var modelStateValue in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelStateValue.Errors)
                {
                    //Use breakpoints and Let's check what it is in these properties
                    var errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
                    var exception = error.Exception;
                }
            }
        }

        ViewBag.GN_Nivel3_CodigoNivel3 = new SelectList(db.GN_Nivel3, "CodigoNivel3", "NombreNivel3", ubicacion.GN_Nivel3_CodigoNivel3);
        ViewBag.GN_CentroDeCosto_CodigoCentroDeCosto = new SelectList(db.GN_CentroDeCosto, "CodigoCentroDeCosto", "NombreCentroDeCosto", ubicacion.GN_CentroDeCosto_CodigoCentroDeCosto);
        return View(ubicacion);
    }
```

Comment: Might be with your regular expressions. I'm not saying that it IS, but you have some nasty ones so all I'm saying is that you should check them one by one. Try parsing your content manually within them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data annotations work as validations on models and when we do model.IsValid then all annotations are validated against the values we assign to model properties , it seems that any of your regular expression is not validating your assigned value.